# flex: Drag and drop- object centering

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

In a drag+drop situation using Flex, I am trying to get the object center aligned to the point of drop- somehow, irrespective of the adjustments to height and width, it is always positioning drop point to left top.

here is the code..

```
imageX = SkinnableContainer(event.currentTarget).mouseX;
imageY = SkinnableContainer(event.currentTarget).mouseY;

// Error checks if imageX/imageY dont satisfy certain conditions- move to a default position
// img.width and img.height are both defined and traced to be 10- idea to center image to drop point

Image(event.dragInitiator).x = imageX-(img.width)/2;
Image(event.dragInitiator).y = imageY-(img.height)/2
```

The last 2 lines don't seem to have any effect. Any ideas why-must be something straightforward, that I am missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xOffset` and `yOffset` properties in the [`doDrag`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/DragManager.html#doDrag%28%29) method of DragManager.

Look [here](http://blog.poweredbyhamsters.com/2007/09/29/drag-and-drop.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following snippet:

```
private function on_drag_start(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var drag_source:DragSource = new DragSource();
    var drag_initiator:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;

    var thumbnail:Image = new Image();
    // Thumbnail initialization code goes here

    var offset:Point = this.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));
    offset.x -= event.stageX;
    offset.y -= event.stageY;
    DragManager.doDrag(drag_initiator, drag_source, event, thumbnail, offset.x + thumbnail.width / 2, offset.y + thumbnail.height / 2, 1.0);
}
```

Here is one important detail. The snippet uses stage coordinate system.
If you use event.localX and event.localY, this approach will fail in some cases. For example, you click-and-drag a movie clip. If you use localX and localY instead of stage coordinates, localX and localY will define coordinates in currently clicked part of the movie clip, not in the whole movie clip.